# How to use canvas.getActiveObject() in curve text case using Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am using curve text in my website its working fine for 1 curve text but when I add another curved text then its generate problem for me . I searched a lot regarding it but cant find solution yet.

Here is My Fiddle [Demo Link1](http://jsfiddle.net/NHs8t/23/)

[Demo Link2](http://jsfiddle.net/NHs8t/25/)

Here is my Code:

```
 canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

  Example = new CurvedText( canvas, {angle:50} );
  Example.center();
  Example2 = new CurvedText( canvas, {angle:150} );
  Example2.center();

  $('.radius, .spacing, .align, .fontSize').change(function(){
    Example.set( $(this).attr('class'), $(this).val() ) ;    
  });
  $('.reverse').change(function(){
    Example.set( 'reverse', ( $(this).val() == 'true' ) ) ;    
  });
  $('.text').keyup(function(){
    Example.setText( $(this).val() ) ;
  });
```

If I use `canvas.getActiveObject()` instead `Example` then its also not working properly:

```
      $('.radius, .spacing, .fontSize, .align').change(function(){
       var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  if(obj){
      obj.set( $(this).attr('class'), $(this).val() ) ;   
    }
      canvas.renderAll();
  });
```

I also tried this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EffEPi/qpJTz/) but it's not working on fiddle also as mention here https://github.com/EffEPi/fabric.curvedText

Comment: FWIW, `fabric.curvedText` that you're using is unofficial plugin developed by someone other than us (fabric team). Need to dive deeper to see what's the problem there but no time right now.

Comment: is this feature present in fabric.js ? if yes then could you just provide me any link where i can got it ?

Comment: Not present at this point